# Deploying an Azure VM and Users with an ARM template and DSC

Tags: powershell, azure-rm-template, dsc

I am taking my first look at creating a DSC (Desired State Configuration) to go with an ARM (Azure Resource Manager) template to deploy a Windows Server 2016 and additional local user accounts. So far the ARM template works fine and for the DSC file I am using simple example to test functionality. The deployment works fine until I try to pass a username/password so I can create a local Windows user account. I can't seem to make this function work at all (see the error message below).

My question is, how do I use the ARM template to pass the credentials (password) to the DSC (mof) file so that the user can be created without having to explicitly allow plain text passwords (which is not a good practice)?

This is what I have tried:

**DSC file**

```
Configuration xUser_CreateUserConfig {
[CmdletBinding()]

Param (

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]
    $nodeName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
    [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
    $Credential
)

Import-DscResource -ModuleName xPSDesiredStateConfiguration

Node $nodeName {
    xUser 'CreateUserAccount' {
        Ensure = 'Present'
        UserName = Split-Path -Path $Credential.UserName -Leaf
        Password = $Credential
    }
}
```

}

**Azure ARM Template Snippet 1st Method**

```
"resources": [
      {
          "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
          "type": "extensions",
          "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
          "location": "[parameters('location')]",
          "tags": {
            "DisplayName": "DSC",
            "Dept": "[resourceGroup().tags['Dept']]",
            "Created By": "[parameters('createdBy')]"
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex(1)))]"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
            "type": "DSC",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "settings": {
              "wmfVersion": "latest",
              "modulesUrl": "[concat(variables('_artifactslocation'), '/', variables('dscArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('dscArchiveFileName'))]",
              "configurationFunction": "xCreateUserDsc.ps1\\xUser_CreateUserConfig",
              "properties": {
                  "nodeName": "[concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex(1))]",
                    "Credential": {
                        "UserName": "[parameters('noneAdminUsername')]",
                        "Password": "PrivateSettingsRef:UserPassword"
                    }
              }
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
              "Items": {
                  "UserPassword": "[parameters('noneAdminUserPassword')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
    ]
```

**Error message**
The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'. VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \\"The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: Compilation errors occurred while processing configuration 'xUser_CreateUserConfig'. Please review the errors reported in error stream and modify your configuration code appropriately. System.InvalidOperationException error processing property 'Password' OF TYPE 'xUser': Converting and storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For more information on securing credentials in MOF file, please refer to MSDN blog: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729

This error message does not help

**Azure ARM Template snippet 2nd Method**

```
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
        "type": "extensions",
        "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "tags": {
          "DisplayName": "DSC",
          "Dept": "[resourceGroup().tags['Dept']]",
          "Created By": "[parameters('createdBy')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
          "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex(1)))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
          "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
          "type": "DSC",
          "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
          "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
          "settings": {
            "wmfVersion": "latest",
            "configuration": {
              "url": "[concat(variables('_artifactslocation'), '/', variables('dscArchiveFolder'), '/', variables('dscArchiveFileName'))]",
              "script": "xCreateUserDsc.ps1",
              "function": "xUser_CreateUserConfig"
            },
            "configurationArguments": {
              "nodeName": "[concat(variables('vmNamePrefix'), copyIndex(1))]"
            },
            "privacy": {
              "dataCollection": "Disable"
            }
          },
          "protectedSettings": {
            "configurationArguments": {
              "Credential": {
                "UserName": "[parameters('noneAdminUsername')]",
                "Password": "[parameters('noneAdminUserPassword')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  ]
```

**Error Message**

VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: "The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name '$credential.Password'. Another common error is to specify parameters of type PSCredential without an explicit type. Please be sure to use a typed parameter in DSC Configuration, for example: configuration Example param([PSCredential] $UserAccount). Please correct the input and retry executing the extension. More information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionDSCWindowsTroubleshoot

This does not help!

I have been trying to solve this error for a couple of days. I have Googled for other example but can only find example of people deploying Web Server and Microsoft's documentation is no help because it tells you to use both of the above methods. When method 1 is the old way  (according to Microsoft). So, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I was setting up parameter in the configuration:

```
# Credentials
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Admincreds,
```

and then in the template:

```
"properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
    "type": "DSC",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "2.19",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
        "configuration": xxx // doesn't matter for this question
        "configurationArguments": yyy // doesn't matter for this question
    },
    "protectedSettings": {
        "configurationArguments": {
            "adminCreds": {
                "userName": "someValue",
                "password": "someOtherValue"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Links to working stuff:
https://github.com/Cloudneeti/PCI_Reference_Architecture/blob/master/templates/resources/AD/azuredeploy.json#L261
https://github.com/Cloudneeti/PCI_Reference_Architecture/blob/master/artifacts/configurationscripts/ad-domain.ps1#L11

ps. you might also need to do [this](https://github.com/Cloudneeti/PCI_Reference_Architecture/blob/master/artifacts/configurationscripts/ad-domain.ps1#L22). Honestly, I dont remember ;)